# How to change Firefox textbox background color?

Tags: firefox, stylish

I use dark theme and want to change textbox background color in Firefox.
How can I do? userContent.css or Stylish?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Stylish CSS will work, if it's OK that every textbox everywhere becomes black text on white background:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);
html input {
  background: #fff !important;
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

You could try removing the `!important` so it's just `#fff;` and `#000;` which should make it only affect textboxes that are unreadable... but this *may* cause trouble on some websites.

Comment: Indeed, though it should be global without the @namespace line, right? And _body_ doesn't seem to be necessary, really? I guess the difference would mean it also applies to input tags that are direct descendents of html, but that's not really a problem, I imagine?

Comment: Not sure whether the `@namespace` line is required, as it doesn't seem to make any difference. But without the `body` tag it will also affect the Firefox UI. That said, `html` is probably a better choice, so I'll change it. Thanks!